# long label title issue in ie

Tags: html, internet-explorer

We are using title tag to display the description of the lables. But when the description is long, the values got trimmed at the end in IE. The same description is showing correctly in firefox.

`<label title="An test used by the test test teszt aaaaa contains combination of numbers to identify the specific state and city in which the subject resides.  Design Note: This element stores the complete test test test as it is being returned by the address standardization application. It might be different from the combination of postal code and the postal code extension code.  Note:  This test any test test test  Extension. If this data has been derived by concatenating the elements Postal Code and Postal Code Extension then these elements will be separated by a hyphen (-). This is a test test test element which test test test test data already test testt test test in the test test test stest tes t Address Line." > Full Test test Code :</label>`

What could be the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest using a `DIV` based toolip via script for IE. IE toolip text seems limited to 512 characters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, we have decided to use jquery tip tip plugin to show the tooltip, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a fixed size buffer that is used to store the tooltip text in IE. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that  `title` attributes are limited to 512 characters. Generally it's not really advised to put novels in the `title` attribute anyway. [»This attribute offers advisory information about the element for which it is set.«](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.3) – it's not really meant for overly long descriptions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we have decided to use jquery tip tip plugin to show the tooltip, thanks a lot